# ios/xcode/core-data: Syntax for simple NSFetch request from entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to fetch an attribute from an entity in core data using the following.  There are no errors but I am getting null as a result, at least from the log results.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

```
- (id) getItems{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Items"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

    NSError *error      = nil;
    NSArray *results    = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                   error:&error];
    NSLog(@"beforevalueforkey%@",results);
    NSMutableArray * items = [[results valueForKey:@"item"] mutableCopy];
    return items;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *items= [self getItems];
    NSLog(@"Here is content of array:%@",items);
}
```

It prints out Here is content of array (null)

Comment: Have you saved some records in core data with entity name "Items" before trying to fetch?

Comment: What does the other NSLog ("beforevalueforkey") show?

Comment: Yes there are several items saved in the store.  The first log output also says (null)

Comment: Please include the code where you are saving records in your question.

Comment: Double check whether `self.managedObjectContext` is nil.

Comment: What is the value of `error` after performing the fetch? Try logging that.

Comment: Found problem.  Forgot to instantiate managedobjectcontext which is in a singleton class.  Adding  the line  self.managedObjectContext = [MyModel sharedInstance].managedObjectContext; got it to work.  Thx to everyone for their suggestions.